# JMeter - HTTP Request Path maximum size to display text

Tags: swing, jmeter

I have a test in JMeter to update details which have many query parameters
I prefer sending them in path instead of create line for each parameter,

The problem that I have more than 256 characters overall (~450) which make Path field not **displaying** the text content:

[image]

Is there a max parameter I can change? Am I'm doing something wrong or it's a bug/limitation in JMeter/Swing component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JMeter 4.0 I don't have this issue, I can write in field any number of characters and it's still visible.

I didn't find specific [change](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) in version 4, but there were UX improvements that may fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [JMeter version 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) you can scroll "Path" with keyboard or mouse, if you don't see a part of your query string - don't worry, it's still there, you can verify it using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

   [image: JMeter Max Path]
2. Another option is investing into a higher-resolution display.
3. Third option is looking into [UrlConfigGui](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/a8f1a2c3acd6f6426f0a6d0e28fe3d2499b35fa9/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/config/gui/UrlConfigGui.java) class, there is a following line there:

   ```
   path = new JLabeledTextField(JMeterUtils.getResString("path"), 80); //$NON-NLS-1$
   ```

   You can try playing with this `80` number, however it will require recompiling JMeter and given the nature of your request I strongly doubt you're capable of this

Comment: 1 - I prefer to see it in UI ( someone can consider it's empty), 2- different resolution didn't helped, 3 - this is a code change, no?

Comment: 3- The problem when I execute locally using ant run_gui I don't see the issue (keeping 80)